# How do I give permission to publish websites to Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How do I give someone permission to publish an ASP.NET MVC website to Azure without just handing over my personal credentials?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the new Azure Resource Manager (ARM) you can use Role Based Access Control (RBAC) to grant a user a certain access on a certain Azure resource that you own.

There are 3 default RBAC roles: `Owner`, `Contributor` and `Reader`.
If you want a user to be able to publish to a site without giving them your personal creds you should be able to add then as a `Contributor` to that particular site and they will be able to see that site in portal and use their own publishing credentials.

This is a much more granular approach than co-admin where the co-admin will have access to your entire subscription.

[Read more about how to setup RBAC in Azure Websites and Publishing here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/01/05/rbac-and-azure-websites-publishing/)

Answer (score 2):

Your options depend on:

1. Azure Websites: you can utilise traditional FTP for uploads and set username / password as required; use deploy from source control systems such as Github (the deployer doesn't even need to know your site details - just the repository to check into); deploy from Dropbox; deploy from Visual Studio using a Publishing Profile (certificate based). [Full details listed on the Azure site](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/).
2. Azure Cloud Services (Web Role): [Publishing Profile](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-create-deploy/).

Websites have a bit more flexibility than Cloud Services and if you use the Publishing Profile approach the user will need to be added to your Azure Subscription as a co-admin (this will change in future but is a restriction today).