# Role of a Software Developer in Azure Environment

Tags: angular, azure

I am developing a angular 4+ project and need to deploy it to Azure Environment and I am new to Azure environment. 
Being a Software developer 
1.what should be my role in Azure?
2.what are the area I should be aware of in Azure environment?.

Comment: As a software developer you should strive to ask more meaningful questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can usually publish directly to azure from visual studio as long as you have the relevant permissions against the subscription group (resource group), and you're signed into an account in VS that has access to it.

There's an SO answer that explains roles a little bit that you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28444824/4486115).

> There are 3 default RBAC roles: Owner, Contributor and Reader. If you
>   want a user to be able to publish to a site without giving them your
>   personal creds you should be able to add then as a Contributor to that
>   particular site and they will be able to see that site in portal and
>   use their own publishing credentials.

It uses a website in the example, but it's the same for pretty much all publishable resources, such as app services, web jobs, etc.

**Note:**

Azure is such a massive cloud computing platform that it's hard to give you specifics. There are so many different types of services that you can use there that it's difficult to generalize advice.